# Determine if three side lengths form an obtuse triangle c++

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement, pythagorean

I have a program that determines whether or not a triangle is an obtuse triangle. The program instructs the user to input 3 side length values (s1,s2,s3). If the squared value of the smaller two side length values is less than the squared value of the largest side value then it is an obtuse triangle.

For Example:

s1 = 3, s2 = 5, s3 = 9

3^2 + 5^2 < 9^2

34 < 81

This is an obtuse triangle.

I have two versions of my program shown below that both give the same output. My question is which one is more efficient? or is there another version that is more efficient than my two versions?

Version 1:

```
double s1,s2,s3;
cout << "Enter three numbers -> ";
cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;
if (max(max(s1,s2),s3) == s1){
    if(pow(s2,2)+pow(s3,2) < pow(s1,2)){
        cout << "This is an obtuse triangle";
    } else {
        cout << "Not an obtuse triangle";
    }
} else if (max(max(s1,s2),s3) == s2){
    if(pow(s1,2)+pow(s3,2) < pow(s2,2)){
        cout << "This is an obtuse triangle";
    } else {
        cout << "Not an obtuse triangle";
    }
} else {
    if(pow(s1,2)+pow(s2,2) < pow(s3,2)){
        cout << "This is an obtuse triangle";
    } else {
        cout << "Not an obtuse triangle";
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
double s1,s2,s3;
cout << "Enter three numbers -> ";
cin >> s1 >> s2 >> s3;
if( max(s1,s2) < s3){
    if(pow(s1,2) + pow(s2,2) < pow(s3,2)){
        cout << "This is an obtuse triangle";
    } else {
        cout << "Not an obtuse triangle";
    }
} else {
    if(pow(min(s1,s2),2) + pow(s3,2) < pow(max(s1,s2),2)){
        cout << "This is an obtuse triangle";
    } else {
        cout << "Not an obtuse triangle";
    }
}
```

Comment: How many of times do you need to compute that? Unless that number is in excess of tens of thousands, I won't worry about it too much.

Comment: `s1 = 3, s2 = 5, s3 = 9` is not an obtuse triangle. It is not a triangle at all.

Comment: Compute the power once and use those values

Comment: @RSahu It doesn’t matter. Both ways will work but I’m asking the question on efficiency because this is a project for one of my classes and my professor wants the most efficient method

Comment: @PrestonWhite, create two functions -- one using the first approach and the second using the second approach. Call them a million times each and see if one is better than the other for identical input.

Comment: @PrestonWhite *and my professor wants the most efficient method* --  Don't use `pow` and just multiply the number by itself.   Unless you have a real smart optimizing compiler, using `pow` to square a number needlessly puts you in running the gauntlet of unneeded mathematical operations.

Comment: Same complexity, but readability can be improved: `bool isObtuse(std::array<double, 3> s){ std::sort(std::begin(s), std::end(s)); return square(s[0]) + square(s[1]) < square(s[2]);}`.

Comment: "My question is which one is more efficient?" - the only way to determine that is to *measure*. Compile your different solutions with different compilers, at different optimization levels and run them all a few million times and *measure* the time spent. Theoretical (big O) performance is not always equal actual performance on a given platform. The real world has surprises for the one who only relies on theory and pure maths.

Comment: write a loop to call the function 1000000 times and see which one is faster

Comment: See also comment by @rici. A triangle satisfies the triangle inequality. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality

Comment: What kind of efficiency you need to optimize for? How much time does this program take on a certain machine with a certain compiler? How many basic operations does it have? How many compares? FLOPS? Average mispredicted branches?

Comment: There is a version which is more efficient than either. (Exactly one conditional if `max` can be implemented without conditional branches.)

Answer (score 0):

Without running a profiler, you can only really gauge the efficiency on how many expensive operations you are performing. In your case, "pow" is the only really expensive operation.

Given both solutions only ever calculate pow(x, 2) once for each value of x (s1, s2, s3), they are equally efficient.

"If" statements and comparisons (the "max" function) are cheap, and not really worth worrying about.

The two solutions are functionally the same.

Comment: If `pow(x,2)` is computed as `x*x` (which some optimizers will do) or if you write it that way, it is really not very expensive: cheaper than a mispredicted branch.

Comment: Given the question is about eye-balling for efficiency, I would have to say a multiplication will take longer than a compare or branch, all things considered. Once compiler optimisations and even CPU architecture come into play this may well stop being true. However, given the question appears to be fairly simplistic, I see no other way to evaluate it.

Comment: all else being equal, which it rarely is, division and unpredictable branches are key offenders. And, of course, cache misses, but that doesn't apply here. Multiplication is surprisingly cheap on most modern hardware. So minimizing unpredictable compares is often a good first approximation. (These days, many processors can do `max` without a branch though.)

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure why I'm arguing with you, here. There are so few instructions, and they are all pretty minimal, that it is really hard to eyeball efficiency. 
'm happy to accept a multiplication is no more costly than a branch. Neither are things that have tripped me up in the past, so unless I was rerunning the same calculation over and over again, I wouldn't be fussed.
Funnily enough, in this example, that point is moot, as the number of branches and multiplications is the same in both examples!

Comment: If `min` and `max` are implemented with a conditional branch, the first code does either 4 or 7 comparisons (expected value 6), while the second does 3 or 4 (expected 3⅔). That would be a clear advantage for the second. However, that is not a likely implementation on most hardware; not counting min and max, the first does (expected) 2⅔ while the second always does 2, which is a smaller difference.